# SQLException при использовании addBatch

Tags: java, preparedstatement

Есть такой метод

```
private void putToForeign(RequestGzk request) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String sql = "INSERT INTO GZK_FOREIGN(GZK_ID, VUS_KLKOD, YEAR, SQU, KNR" +
                ") values(?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {
            con = dp.getDsSrc().getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            for(int i = 0; i < request.getObjArray().getObj().size(); i++) {
                if(request.getObjArray().getObj().get(i).getObjSZArray().get(0).getObjSz() != null){
                    ps.setString(1, String.valueOf(request.getObjArray().getObj().get(i).getId()));
                    ps.setString(2, request.getObjArray().getObj().get(i).getObjSZArray().get(0).getObjSz().get(0).getVusKlkod());
                    ps.setString(3, request.getObjArray().getObj().get(i).getObjSZArray().get(0).getObjSz().get(0).getYear());
                    ps.setString(4, request.getObjArray().getObj().get(i).getObjSZArray().get(0).getObjSz().get(0).getSqu());
                    ps.setString(5, request.getObjArray().getObj().get(i).getKnr());
                    ps.addBatch();
                }
            }
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch(SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(GzkParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

когда вызываю кидает exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ошибка при пакетировании: batch must be either executed or cleared
```

`ps.addBatch();` - побывал заменить на `ps.executeBatch()`  или на ps.execute()
тогда цикл не правильно функционировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй `ps.executeUpdate();` заменить  на `ps.executeBatch()`